# Grails get any of the children in a hasMany

Tags: grails, has-many, grails-orm

I have a domain class which has many of another domain class.  I want any one of the children and don't care which.  Example

```
class MyDomainClass {
  static hasMany = [thingies:OtherDomainClass]
}
```

I can do this the stupid way like:

```
def findOne
myInstance.thingies.each{
  findOne=it
}
```

But is there a better way like:

```
def findOne = myInstance.thingies.grabTheMostConvenientOne()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`thingies` is a Collection, so you have everything from [Collection](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html) at your disposal.

A simple way you might do this is:

```
def one = myInstance.thingies.asList().first()
```

However, you probably want to make sure the collection actually has some elements first. The documentation doesn't explicitly say that `first()` throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException if the list is empty, but I have a feeling it still might. If that's the case, you probably want:

```
def one = myInstance.thingies.size() > 0 ? myInstance.thingies.asList().first() : null
```

Or, if you want to be super-concise at the expense of some readability, you can use this approach ([courtesy John Wagenleitner)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839834/get-the-first-element-of-a-list-idiomatically-in-groovy/4840311#4840311):

```
def one = myInstance.thingies?.find { true }
```