# Getting the first element of list

Tags: grails

I create objects from the class called `Company`. How can I get the very first created object?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839834/get-the-first-element-of-a-list-idiomatically-in-groovy

Answer (score 0):

If `Company` is a persistent object (an instance of a domain class), this should work

```
def firstCompany = Company.first()
```